# Changing / Manipulating prices in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to make a "tax-toggle" script that can change the view of the prices when clicking a button. The prices can be viewed with or without taxes. I'm using WordPress/WooCommerce.

Right now it works partly, but I'm having some difficulties to keeps the prices in the cart changed, when a new product is added, the page is reloaded or if a new page is loaded. The rest of the prices on the site keeps changed. It's all done in JavaScript/jQuery.

**This is how it works:**

1. The customer hit the toggle button, and the prices are changing.
2. jQuery are storing a cookie, containing the toggle choice *(`incl` / `excl`)*.
3. When the user refresh the page or switching page the cookies is loading and immediately changing the prices according to the choice.

> **Side Note:**  The total price on the cart and checkout page is always
>   displaying the prices incl. tax, since that is what the customer are
>   going to pay, regardless of the choice.
>
> Business-customers should just have the possibility the see the prices
>   without tax since the tax can be deducted.

### The Actual Problem

The actual problem I'm facing, is that when the prices has been changed and a new product is added or the page is refreshed / switched, the prices in the mini-cart and the cart/checkout page, keeps the original prices. I guess this is because that when the page is loaded, the content of these are somehow loaded via. AJAX, and the tax-changes are then replaced.

I've tried to call my change-tax-prices function with 'updated_wc_div' and 'updated_cart_totals' but none of them have worked:

```
jQuery( document.body ).on( 'updated_wc_div updated_cart_totals', function() {
   toggle_prices_on_page();
} );
```

So I want to find a way to keep the price-changes it the cart/checkout, without any AJAX-replacements. Is that possible and if so, how do I achieve that?

In fact, I don't even know if this is the right way to achieve what I want, at all.
At the beginning, before turning to JavaScript, I tried to manipulate the WooCommerce core price-functions, but that did not end up well.

Thanks you very much :)